# What is the derivative of $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ where $f(z)=z\bar z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the derivative of $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ where $f(z)=z\bar z$?

Not sure how to go about differentiating this function.

Is it just $f'(z)=\bar z$? Not sure if this makes sense since $\bar z \in \mathbb C$, and not in $\mathbb R$ in general.

Comment: If you mean the complex derivative with respect to $z$, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that $f(z)=|z|^2$

Comment: The derivative would be $\overline  z$ if $\overline z$ were not a function of $z$, but $\overline z$ is a function of $z$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So shouldn't we use product rule somehow?

Comment: @AlJebr:  that would be a good thought, but $g(z)=\overline z$ is not differentiable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this function is not holomorphic, i.e. the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}
$$ 
does not exist.

You may consider the function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$. This function is differentiable and its Jacobian is $\begin{pmatrix} 2x & 2y\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: There is a point at which the complex derivative does exist. It exists at $z=0$. Being holomorphic is not exactly the same as existence of complex derivative.

Comment: @egorovik good point! (in both senses of the phrase :) )

Answer (score 2):

For $z=(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and we are to compute
\begin{align*}
\lim_{w\in\mathbb{C},w\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(z+w)-f(z)}{w}.
\end{align*}
If we let $w=(h,0)=h$ and send $h\rightarrow 0$, we get 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|(x+h)+iy|^{2}-|x+iy|^{2}}{h}=\dfrac{(x+h)^{2}-x^{2}}{h}\rightarrow 2x.
\end{align*}
If we set $w=(h,k)=h+ik$ and send both $h=k\rightarrow 0$, we get
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|(x+h)+i(y+k)|^{2}-|x+iy|^{2}}{h+ik}=\dfrac{2h(x+y)+2h^{2}}{(1+i)h}\rightarrow\dfrac{2(x+y)}{1+i}=(1-i)(x+y).
\end{align*} 
We must have $x+y=2x$ and $-(x+y)=0$, but if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, the system has no solution.